# Solving for Machine Dimensions of Cable Robot

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, kinematics

I am building an open source cable robot similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCa8uDFzbsw) except constrained to two dimensions. I precisely know the lengths of all four cables, and from them I would like to derive the locations of the anchor points of the cables ($A,B,D$).

[image: Initial position]

Essentially the known quantities are:

$$C = (0,0)$$
$$|\vec{AE}|$$
$$|\vec{BE}|$$
$$|\vec{CE}|$$
$$|\vec{DE}|$$

This is not enough information to constrain the positions of $A,B,D$, however I am able to move the robot to a new position giving us a second set of information.

[image: Second position]

So now we also know:

$$|\vec{AE'}|$$
$$|\vec{BE'}|$$
$$|\vec{CE'}|$$
$$|\vec{DE'}|$$

Is this enough information to solve for the positions of $A, B, C$? And if so how would I go about beginning to solve for them?

**Edit:** I think we may also need to arbitrarily constrain the whole system from rotating by saying that $Dy = 0$. Without that arbitrary constraint there would be infinite solutions where the whole system rotates around C...I think.

**Edit 2:** One more option that we have to constrain things further is to position E such that $|\vec{AE}|$ is parallel to $|\vec{DE}|$. If possible I would like to avoid using that unless it is necessary.

Thanks for taking the time to read all the way to the bottom.

Comment: It seems that the cables are stretchable. Basically two cables will define in the plan two locations. A third one will determine which one may be selected - but again it need to be precisely calculated based on the other two. It seems to me that you calculate the length of the cables to decide where you want the position E be.

Comment: You are correct that during normal operation the length of the cables defines where the position E is, however after the initial setup we don't know where B,C,D are so we can't compute E. The goal is to find B,C,D knowing the lengths of the cables.

Comment: Is your goal to calculate the lengths to position E'

Comment: No, the goal is to find the coordinates of A, B, D

Comment: If I understand your goal - you want to fix A and to get E' moved in controlled way by means of selecting B, C, D? Since the measures of the strings are given you just need to position on circles according to the string measures - actually two are enough (you do not need three)

Comment: Sort of, knowing Cx and Cy plus the lengths of all the strings can I find Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Dx? Is my real question. The answer is no (I think) so then it's a matter of figuring out what other information I need

Comment: You can use the information to optimize the control to move E'. By moving the points A, B and D minimally to the circles around the target E' you will select the locations for A' B and D.